# Spider in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, theory

Is it theoretically possible to build a spider in ActionScript3 without using server-side middleware technologies? Nothing very advanced (only visiting an HTML page and returning the HTML as text to the swf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** *(Question was updated to be more specific)*

You can't access random domains without valid policy files.  But you can use ExternalInterface and set [allowScriptAccess=always](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16494.html) to open the page in another browser frame and pass the result data via JavaScript.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Theoretically, any language that can load and parse web pages could be used to crawl them - the question is: Would you want to?

Here's a couple of things to think about:

1. Flash/Flex is used mostly for client-side applications, i.e. programs that provide elaborate UI features and/or visualization.  Although it has grown and evolved into a powerful programming environment - that's what it does best, so that's what it should primarily be used for.  I mean: Of course, given time and patience, you could write a web application in pure assembly language - but why not use the tools that were invented for that?
2. ActionScript certainly isn't the fastest language you could build an HTML parser with. The program will run single-threaded, only on one machine at a time.  Scaling out could probably be done by implementing a [P2P network](http://www.flashrealtime.com/basics-of-p2p-in-flash/), but again: That technology was meant for other things, and there are solutions that are much better at creating scalable search mechanisms.
3. Depending on what kind of web pages you are going to crawl, and how many, you'll end up with a lot of data.  Sooner or later, storing, indexing and retrieving any data you have collected, will become far more important than the crawling itself.

   If you chose to work file-based, you'd have to at least use AIR, because standard ActionScript has very limited file read/write capabilities - without an asynchronous access method, like [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html), your program would become slower and less responsive over time.

   Also, distributed solutions would become even more complex, because each node would have to keep a portion of the indexed results, and in addition to searching and indexing, you'd have to implement some kind of lookup mechanism, such as [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

   So you'll probably want to use existing storage technology - a database and / or search engine.

All in all, I would strongly advise to make a list of the important features you want your spider to have:

- Who will be working with your program, and what is its purpose?
- Is it meant to run automatically, or do you want some kind of user interaction to control it?
- What kind of data are you going to collect, and how do you want to access it?
- How much data are you going to store, and do you have an infrastructure you can build on?

Once you've answered these questions, you should look at existing tools that might help you implement some or all of the features, and only after you've done that, decide on a technology to implement what can't be solved otherwise.

Comment: +1 for the unappreciated effort. Maybe you shouldn't remove the whole post. Even if the details of the question changed, it's still good info and could be useful for other people.

Comment: @weltraumpirat: first of all thanks for your kind reply. Moreover, I could not submit the practical solution I found because my "82" isn't enough to auto-reply. Fundamentally there's a website that contains some updated articles about football matches. I wanted to show the results in real-time in my swf. I did it with less than 10 lines of code (but, of course, if the page changes over time, the swf will be broken).

Comment: You could just look for an rss news feed... But anyway: that's not really a spider, then.

Comment: They have no rss feed   :-)   This is not related to Bundesliga, SerieA or Liga. It is something absolutely peripheral (dilectantistic championships), so you can't find very easily informations and there are two websites with no RSS feeds.